# How to iterate a matrix in haskell

Tags: file, loops, haskell, matrix, io

I need to iterate a matrix in Haskell and I don't know how to do it.

I have my matrix in a `.txt` file so I get the content with this line: `contents <- readFile file`, and then I need to iterate that matrix one by one, because I need to convert the values to a JValue.

This is my code:

```
myFunction file = do 
contents <- readFile file      
let element = endBy "," contents
print(element)
```

What can I do?

Comment: I think your question is "what's the Haskell equivalent of iteration".

Comment: in Haskell **what** you want to do is more important then how - so it's nice that you want to iterate but it does not help us answer your question - can you please give an example of your input and expected output and what you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how you wanna represent matrix, but this is my solution:

```
import System.IO

convLine::String -> [String]
convLine (x:[]) = ["b"]
convLine (x:xs) = ["a"] ++ convLine xs

convMatrix::[String] -> [[String]]
convMatrix (x:[]) = [convLine x]
convMatrix (x:xs) = [convLine x] ++ convMatrix xs

main = do 
    handler <- openFile "./matrix" ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents handler
    let input = lines content
    print $ convMatrix input
```

Content of my input file ./matrix was 
123 
123 
123

and my result is: 
[["a","a","b"],["a","a","b"],["a","a","b"]]
I've just showed example how to convert values in some kind of matrix representation.

Comment: Thank for all your answers, maybe i don't explain myself crearly, the thing is that I have a matrix in a file called "matrix.txt", i have something like this: [["team;country;name;years"],["X;X;X;N"],["Team A;USA;Building A1;4.57"],["Team B;COL;Building B2;9.32"]...]
What I need is how can I iterate every single element of this list, because I need to convert the values into a Jvalue. Thank you